Ошибка записи чисел типа 'float' при file.to_csv()
Ожидаемый файл должен выглядеть таким образом:

Однако, после скачивания его из Google Colab получается следующее:

Код, которым я преобразовывал pd.DataFrame в CSV:
submission.to_csv('submission2.csv', index=False, sep=',')


А в самом датафрейме submission данные правильные? Покажите submission.head(), покажите submission.info(), покажите submission2.csv в текстовом редакторе как выглядит, а не в экселе.

Оказалось, проблемы с отображением данных в WPS Office.
В Excel и Libre Calc все отображается корректно.

Постарайтесь оставлять более развернутые ответы. Изменить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].
